# /workspaces/{workspaceName}, query param "quietOnNotFound" always throws an exception with 404 code

Tags: geoserver, c#, geoserver-rest-api, asp.net

I am working with WebRequest Class in .NET and the url I have built is `"workspaces/" + worspace_name + ".xml?quietOnNotFound=" + true"`

This works well if the workspace exists but always throws an exception with `error code 404` if the workspace does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Geoserver [official documents](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/workspaces.html#rest-api-workspaces-quietonnotfound), if the workspace doesn't exist, it retruns `404 Not Found` even if you send `quietOnNotFound=true` parameters in `GET` request. The only difference you can see just happens inside the geoserver .bat window.

If you send a `GET` request for fetching `workspace` that doesn't exist, you can see a message printed inside .bat window:

```
/geoserver/rest/workspaces/test.xml
responseCode => 404
responseMessage => No such workspace: 'test' found
```

[image: log message inside geoserver cmd]

Meanwhile, geoserver provides you `quietOnNotFound=true` parameter that helps you to avoid geoserver prints this log message. However, as geoserver is telling us, you will receive `404 Not Found` as a response anyway.

```
/geoserver/rest/workspaces/test.xml?quietOnNotFound=true
responseCode => 404
responseMessage => ''
```

[image: no log message]

Please notice this is a REST API standard and not an `exception` when you receive `404 Not Found` as response. You can handle this situation and inform the users that the workspace you are looking for, doesn't exist. This can be helpful when a user wants to create a new workspace and the system should check if this `name` already exists or not.